# WARNING: ol is now only supported by Docker EE Check https://store.docker.com for information on Docker EE

Tags: docker, centos

I am getting below error when trying to install the Docker on centOs. Following link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-centos-7 for the same.

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
# Executing docker install script, commit: 4957679


  WARNING: ol is now only supported by Docker EE
           Check https://store.docker.com for information on Docker EE
```

Comment: I have successfully installed docker on a centos host following the official guidelines. [Docker CE](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/) & [Docker EE](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/centos/)

Comment: What I should used for VERSION_STRING?

Comment: If you wish to install the latest version, you should skip this step. It is useful only if you have to install a specific version. Normally, after `sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo`,  execute `sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`. This will install the latest version in the newly added repo.

Comment: Thanks.. I got this error.. even try to install these packages... but still error
`You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`